# SQL - Advanced duplicates removal using ID NOT IN

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates, aggregate-functions

I found duplicates in my table which needed to be removed. The table contains:

1. ID - unique key for table
2. STUDENT_ID - id of student
3. SUBJECT_ID - subject of student
4. CLASS_ID - class student is in
5. XP_LVL - level of expertise

One student should have only one record of subject, class and XP_lvl. In this case the removal of duplicities is based on delete all but keep one.

In my case duplicates looks like this:

| ID | STUDENT_ID | SUBJECT_ID | CLASS_ID | EXPERTISE_LVL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1AAA | 55FFE | CLASS808 | 2 |
| 2 | 1AAA | 55FFE | CLASS808 | 2 |
| 3 | 2AAB | 49BB | CLASS890 | 3 |
| 4 | 2AAB | 49BB | CLASS890 | 3 |
| 5 | 2AAB | 49BB | CLASS890 | 4 |
| 6 | 2AAB | 49BB | CLASS890 | 3 |

I have identified all the duplicates by creating unique ID of `(CONCAT(STUDENT_ID, CONCAT(SUBJECT_ID, CLASS_ID)))` and then by `having count.. >1` which works fine.

Now I need to identify all the ID so I can use `ID NOT IN (SELECT...)` in my delete from query.

So I did this ..

```
AND ID NOT IN (SELECT UID FROM (
SELECT
    min(ID) AS UID,
    STUDENT_ID,
    SUBJECT_ID,
    CLASS_ID    
FROM
    my_table 
GROUP BY
    STUDENT_ID,
    SUBJECT_ID,
    CLASS_ID    
HAVING
    count(CONCAT(STUDENT_ID, CONCAT(SUBJECT_ID, CLASS_ID))) > 1))
```

However I cannot use `min/max(ID)` to choose which ID to keep because as you can see for student 2AAB there are duplicities with different XP_LVL.

In this case I need to select ID of highest XP_LVL to keep and delete all other.

I tried using RANK, ROWNUM different ordering and loaaads of subselects but without desired results.

Does anyone have any idea how to do it effectively ? We are talking about 6k duplicities so I cant do it one by one.
Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Don't use `CONCAT`enated values to determine duplicates as it will go wrong. For example, if the students have ids `12` and `123` and they takes subjects with ids `345` and `45` respectively then when you concatenate the numbers you get `12345` for both even though they are not the same.

Comment: I use concat because in the table the ID are hexadecimal values.. I dont think i will get it wrong because the UID is in real for example "8a12d16c669453540166962b208b000a6BB9728FB50000000000001".. it will be unique I am sure of it. I just made up numbers for better interpretation of question however thank you good point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function and correlate the deletion using the `ROWID` pseudo-column:

```sql
DELETE FROM my_table
WHERE ROWID IN (
  SELECT ROWID
  FROM   (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
             PARTITION BY student_id, subject_id, class_id
             ORDER BY expertise_lvl DESC
           ) AS rn
    FROM   my_table
  )
  WHERE  rn > 1
)
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1166b87bb9071345efa83b1e57713fdf)*

Comment: Thank you so much.. its briliant